# How select first N items in Java TreeMap?

Tags: java, dictionary

Given this map

```
SortedMap<Integer, String> myMap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
```

Instead of a for loop is there a utility function to copy first N items to a destination map?

Comment: I haven't check but I wouldn't be surprised if some Google Java API had a one-liner to do just that :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe, but not as part of the standard Java API. And: the utility would use a loop inside.

So you'll need a loop, but you can create your own "utility" by doing it all in a static method in a utility class:

```
public static SortedMap<K,V> putFirstEntries(int max, SortedMap<K,V> source) {
  int count = 0;
  TreeMap<K,V> target = new TreeMap<K,V>();
  for (Map.Entry<K,V> entry:source.entrySet()) {
     if (count >= max) break;

     target.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
     count++;
  }
  return target;
}
```

The complexity is still O(n) (I doubt, that one can achieve O(1)) but you use it like a tool without "seeing" the loop:

```
SortedMap<Integer, String> firstFive = Util.putFirstEntries(5, sourceMap);
```

Answer (score 30):

Using the power of Java 8+:

```
TreeMap<Integer, String> myNewMap = myMap.entrySet().stream()
    .limit(3)
    .collect(TreeMap::new, (m, e) -> m.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue()), Map::putAll);
```

Answer (score 7):

There's [`SortedMap.headMap()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html#headMap%28K%29) however you'd have to pass a key for the element to go up to. You could iterate N elements over [`Map.keySet()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29) to find it, e.g.:

```
Integer toKey = null;
int i = 0;
for (Integer key : myMap.keySet()) {
    if (i++ == N) {
        toKey = key;
        break;
    }
}

// be careful that toKey isn't null because N is < 0 or >= myMap.size()
SortedMap<Integer, String> copyMap = myMap.headMap(toKey);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an ordored iterator to get the first x records, orderer by descending id for instance :

```
Iterator<Integer> iterator = myMap.descendingKeySet().iterator();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the putAll(Map t) function to copy the items from the map to specified map.But it copies all the items. You cannot copy fixed number of items.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll%28java.util.Map%29